# How to filter the data in ng-repeat based on the values of the angular-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: angularjs

I am showing the data in the table using `ng-repeat`. Now I have to filter the data using the based on the checked values of the angular dropdown `multiselect`. How to do that can anyone help me?

Comment: Show your code samples or better setup jsfiddle example with your case.

Comment: This doesnt have anything to do with ruby-on-rails.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to make some assumptions. The first is that you are using the first Angular Dropdown Multiselect that i saw when i googled it. It looks like their site might be a bit broken, but what i gather is that your model should be an array of objects each with an ID and Display. You can use a filter in this case. In the filter, just compile an array based off of the ID's that match. So if your controller looks like:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.FilterPhrase = [ 
                {ID:6, Display:"Display6"},//this wont show up
                {ID:3, Display:"Display3"},
                {ID:1, Display:"Display1"}];
  $scope.myData = [{ID:1, Display:"Display1"},
                   {ID:2, Display:"Display2"},
                   {ID:3, Display:"Display3"},
                   {ID:4, Display:"Display4"},
                   {ID:5, Display:"Display5"}];
});
```

Then create a filter:

```
app.filter('multifilter', function () {
return function (list, filterdata) {
        var results = [];

    filterdata.forEach(function(a){
            var r = list.find(function(b){
                return a.ID==b.ID;
        });
        results.push(r);          
        });
   return results;
};
});
```

and finally, call it at the end of your ng-repeat

```
 <tr ng-repeat="n in myData | multifilter:FilterPhrase">
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brhardwick/promv3e1/2/